# Get all Indexes of the set bits in a BitSet

Tags: java, bitset

I'm looking for a fast algorithm with gives me all the indexes of the set bits in a BitSet object. 
This is slow:

```java
BitSet bitSet = ...
Collection<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>(bitSet.cardinality());
int nextSetBit = bitSet.nextSetBit(0);
for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.cardinality(); ++i ) {
    indexes.add(nextSetBit);
    nextSetBit = bitSet.nextSetBit(nextSetBit + 1);
}
...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read this nice article http://java-performance.info/bit-sets/

Answer (score 20):

No need to use `bitSet.cardinality()` at all:

```
for (int i = bitSet.nextSetBit(0); i != -1; i = bitSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
    indexes.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As specified in [BitSet#nextSetBit(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit-int-) javadocs :

```
//To iterate over the true bits in a BitSet, use the following loop:
for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
     // operate on index i here
     if (i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
         break; // or (i+1) would overflow
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Java 8 you can use BitSet's `stream()` method.

> **IntStream    stream()**
>
> Returns a stream of indices for which this BitSet contains a bit in the set state.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution:

```
val indexes = MutableList<Int>()
var i = bitSet.nextSetBit(0)
while (i != -1) {
    indexes.add(i)
    i = bitSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bitset.toString()` will return all the true bit index
like
`10010100`
`{2, 4, 7}`
so you can transfer`{2, 4, 7}`to java list

Answer (score -1):

Change the loop (you increase the complexity to O(N^2) because you call cardinality() in each loop iteration):

```
for (int e = bitSet.cardinality(), i = 0; i < e; ++i ) {
    indexes.add(nextSetBit);
    nextSetBit = bitSet.nextSetBit(nextSetBit + 1);
}
```

Comment: @myborobudur If it didn't help your perceived slowness most likely is *not* caused by the BitSet (either its so small it doesn't matter *or* the autoboxing to Integer overshadows it by far). Use a profiler to measure.

Comment: It is better to use the solution that does not call cardinality()